# Android Studio 2.3.2 - отладка конфигурации?

Tags: android, android-studio

Впервые решил попробовать кодить приложения для андроид и установил последний рилиз студии.
Так как комп у меня слабый, то крайняя версия не заработала, и я решил начать с версии 2.3.2.
После установки и создания нового проекта появилась такая ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете решения разные: от исправления текста в конфигурации и установки разных API до утверждений, что уже "ничего не поддерживается" - ничего в моем варианте не сработало.
Может есть варианты запустить текущую версию?
Текущая конфигурация на которую ссылается логгер выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 2.3.2 ну это прям совсем древность, установите 4.2.2, ну или хотя бы 3.6.3, она по крайней мере о androidx библиотеках знает, которые на замену com.android.support пришли

Comment: @leonardik, прикладывайте текстовую информацию [в виде текста](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120), а не скриншотами. Также [добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1482080/edit) в ваш вопрос содержимое файла `build.gradle`, который лежит в корне вашего проекта.